# Why doesn't this type declaration work?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to create a 'Person' type where each person has a sex and a name.

```
data Sex = Sex Char deriving Show

male   = Sex 'M'
female = Sex 'F'

data Name   = Name [Char]      deriving Show

data Person = Person { 
    Sex    :: Sex,
    Name   :: Name
} deriving (Show)
```

When I try to load this in ghci I just get the unhelpful error `parse error on input 'Sex'`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just a random PS, if you would define this like you would a boolean data value, then there's much less possibilities, and less bugs.  For example, what if somebody called a function with (Sex 'Z')?  I'd suggest the following:  data Sex = Female | Male deriving (...)

Comment: @codebliss, thanks, I forgot about the `|` trick for types. (I am a *really* n00bish n00b.)

Comment: Its not the question you asked, but you would be better defining Sex as "data Sex = Male | Female".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem lies in your usage of upper case inside the record syntax. The code should look like:

```
data Person = Person { sex :: Sex, name :: Name }...
```

Trying that, the code seems to at least compile. Since "sex" and "name" are not types (while "Sex" and "Name" are), you cannot make the first letters upper case.

Comment: That's it exactly, thanks! I'm still learning the difference between type constructors, value constructors, etc. All very confusing and new to me. :)

Comment: I learned Haskell this summer, and it was a very rewarding experience. Hang in there!